# Passing variable to jsp:include is not working

Tags: jsp, foreach, scope

I have a jsp file with the following

```
<c:forEach var="node" items="${tree.children}">
  <c:set var="currentNode" value="${node}" scope="request"/>
  <c:out value="${currentNode.displayName}" />
  <jsp:include page="currentNode.jsp"/>
  <br/>
</c:forEach>
```

with currentNode.jsp containing, at the moment, only

```
X<c:out value="${currentNode.displayName}" />Y
```

The variable `currentNode` should be available in the included jsp file. For example, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799716/passing-cforeach-variable-to-a-jspinclude).

But even this simple example is not working. I am getting the following output

```
Node 1 XY
Node 2 XY
Node 3 XY
```

Where I was expecting

```
Node 1 XNode 1Y
Node 2 XNode 1Y
Node 3 XNode 1Y
```

What am I missing to make this work?

Comment: What container impl/version? What if you just use `<jsp:param>` the usual way?

Comment: Have you checked the generated HTML code? How does it look like. My bet is that you forgot to declare the core taglib in your included JSP.

Comment: @JBNizet You are exactly correct. The parameter was being passed but I did not have the core taglib defined. My c:out was being added to the page literally, not interpreted.

Comment: BTW, @JBNizet, put this as an answer and I will select it.

Comment: @DaveIsaacs: I've added the answer. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bet is that you forgot to declare the core taglib in your included JSP. The `<c:out>` tags will thus be sent as is to the output, and the browser will ignore them. Check the generated HTML code.